# Maximize square of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $A$ be a symmetric $2 \times 2$ real matrix and let $x=(x_1,x_2)^T$ be a vector such that $\|x\| = 1$. We know that the quadratic form $x A x^T$ is maximal if $x$ is parallel to an eigenvector corresponding to the greatest eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. My question is when $(x A x^T)^2$ is maximal?

Comment: in case some eigenvalues might be negative, you want the eigenvector where the eigenvalue has largest absolute value. Just think of a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $1, -2$

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you.